# Menu is falling behind the panel in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a start menu panel just like in Sencha Desktop example. I have multiple menus in the panel. When click on menuitem the sub menu panel is getting rendered, but while clicking on other area the sub menu panel is hiding behind the main panel.

And even when I click on main menu items the menu panel is hiding.

I want to prevent the click event on the main menu items. And prevent the sub menu panel being hidden behind the main panel.

Please have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please send your HTML code with css or a fiddle link will be better to solve your issue. If you have live site url then you can give the url also.

Comment: It is completely written on Javascript through Sencha Architect. The behavior is completely in-built configurations. Not custom code.

Comment: You can give your site url.

Comment: I am sorry I can't. You need to have a VPN connection which is highly confidential and restricted. It's Project Specific!

Comment: Then it's not possible to find a solution without code or url.

Comment: I assume you don't have any idea about Extjs applications. Anyway Thanks for help!

Comment: I hope it may be z index issue but without looking any code no body can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My solution was to check if there is a submenu and bring this submenu to the front.

So in my controller on the click event of the menu i did the following :

```
if (menuitem.menu) {
menuitem.menu.toFront();
return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have used some other plugin to make it always on top by using z-index property.